# Regular expression inquiry

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using Ruby to do a simple substring type match. I'm trying to understand why the following happens:

```
irb(main):024:0> puts "match" if "foo" =~ /foo/
match
=> nil
irb(main):025:0> puts "match" if "foo" =~ /foo,/
=> nil
```

how can this regex be modified so that if any part of the search criteria matches "foo", a match is made?

Comment: What is wrong with your first regex ?

Comment: I think you may be confusing which is the string to be matched and which is the regex.  The bit between the /'s is the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your comparisons backwards:

```
"foo".match(/foo,/) # See if "foo" matches the pattern "foo,"
# => nil
"foo,".match(/foo/) # See if "foo," matches the pattern "foo"
# => #<MatchData "foo">
```

The `=~` operator is a bit of history that has fallen out of style because it's not self-explanatory.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the scan method of String and pass in the regex you want to check against.

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > puts "match" if "foo".scan(/foo,/)
match
=> nil
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `scan` will always return an array, even an empty one as in this case.

Comment: It's also a poor use of `scan` when more direct regex checks are available.